# Spring Security: At which point do I get to know that a user logged in?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I am using spring security with URL based interceptors to secure my application. In which classes/at which points can I do some custom processing after a user logged in?

I specifically want to save the date the user logged in last, but I cannot figure out how to achieve this.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider implementing the [org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html) interface.

You would then listen specifically for the [org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AuthenticationSuccessEvent](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/event/AuthenticationSuccessEvent.html).

You could then persist your user's login.

Possible example code:

```
public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {

    if (event instanceof AuthenticationSuccessEvent) {

        try {

            AuthenticationSuccessEvent authenticationSuccessEvent = (AuthenticationSuccessEvent) event;

            Authentication authentication = authenticationSuccessEvent.getAuthentication();

            //Persist your user's login here.

        } catch (Exception e) {

            // Handle exception as needed.
        }
    }
}
```