# Application Listener not receiving event notification

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, listener

I'm working on a spring MVC application using Spring Security for validation.  I'd like to do some work upon login, and have seen the suggestion in multiple places (inlcuding [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668634/spring-security-at-which-point-do-i-get-to-know-that-a-user-logged-in)) to achieve this using an Application Listener.  I've gone ahead and implemented it as such:

```
@Named
public class AccountLoginListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

    @Inject
    AccountService accountService;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
        Account account = (Account) event.getAuthentication().getDetails();
        ...
        accountService.saveAccount(account);
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, the AuthenticationSuccessEvent doesn't seem to be getting captured, and when I debug, the onApplicationEvent function is never called.  I haven't done any additional configurations in xml files, but I don't think it should be necessary to do so.  Am I missing some configuration, or am I doing something else wrong?

Thanks!

idbentley

Comment: How are you creating instantiating this bean/listener?

Comment: My spring context has a `<context:component-scan>`, whose base package this class is within.

Comment: what type is the `@Named` annotation?

Comment: It is a jsr330 annotation, which is functionally equivalent (I believe) to `@Component`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spring Security 3 you should implement [`AuthenticationSuccessHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html), and then configure this bean in your application context.

Comment: Thanks for this David - I'll have a look at what the differences are.  My problem ended up being because the web-context in our application is a different context from the spring context.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class AuthenticationSuccessListener
    implements ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

    @Inject
    AccountService accountService;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
        Account account = (Account) event.getAuthentication().getDetails();
        accountService.saveAccount(account);
    }
}
```